# MongoDB callback return issue for nested call

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am attempting to place a nested MongoDB call within an API I have been working on. The goal of the API is to update a persons goal based on exercise perform. The issue I currently have is trying to get the exercise events into the main function to enable me to compute "completeness".

I welcome any comments you may have on this issue.

Hello everyone,

I am attempting to place a nested MongoDB call within an API I have been working on.The goal of the API is to update a persons goal based on exercise perform.The issue I currently have is trying to get the exercise events into the main
function to enable me to compute "completeness".

I welcome any comments you may have on this issue.

```
module.exports.generateGoal = function(request, response) {

//User ID 
var user_id = new ObjectId(request.params.id);

//Goal Search
Goals.find({
    user_id: user_id,
    active_goal: true
}, function(err, goals) {
    if (err) {
        //Error: send error to user
        throw err
    } else {
        if (goals.length == 0) { //No goals, do nothing
            return response.json({
                success: true,
                msg: "No Goal"
            });
        } else { //User as goals, therefore pull in exercise

            for (i = 0; i < goals.length; i++) {
                //Looking to have exercise available here for computation
                queryExercise(user_id, goals[i].start_date, goals[i].end_date, function(result) {
                    //Exercise able to be accessed here
                    console.log(result)
                    return result
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
};

function queryExercise(user_id, start_date, end_date, callback) {
    ExerciseData.find({
        user_id: user_id,
        exercise_date: {
            $gte: start_date,
            $lt: end_date
        }
    }, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else if (result.length > 0) {
            callback(result);
        }
    });
}
```

**Edit 2:**

I am very grateful for the response below which does exactly what I need. Thinking towards the future where any goal can have multiple exercises what would be the best method to employ to obtain an output similar to:

```
    {
    _id: dfhdjds8348hhj8
    goal_id: 1
    exercises: { {
      exercise: 1,
      type: running
    },
    {
      exercise: 2,
      type: running
    }
  }
}.
{
    _id: ddhdjds8342hhj8
    goal_id: 2
    exercises: { {
      exercise: 1,
      type: jumping
    },
    {
      exercise: 2,
      type: rowing
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit 3:**

After implementing the new code below, I have noticed that it is not able to return the correct values. I wanted to provide some further information on the modals and syntax that I use.

Goals

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Define goal model schema
var GoalsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user_id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true
    },
    active_goal: Boolean,
    goal_id: Number,
    start_date: Date,
    end_date: Date
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

// Export user model
module.exports = mongoose.model('Goals', GoalsSchema);
```

Exercise data

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Define user model schema
var exercisesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user_id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true
    },
    exercise_date: Date,
    exercise_type: String  
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

// Export user model
module.exports = mongoose.model('exercises', exercisesSchema);
```

And the syntax I am using in the code is as follow,s not the additional changes that I had to make to get it to work properly.

```
module.exports.generateGoal = function(request, response) {

    //User ID
    var user_id = new ObjectId(request.params.id); //User ID

    //Goal query
    Goals.aggregate([{
                "$match": {
                    "user_id": user_id,
                    "active_goal": true
                }
            },
            {
                "$lookup": {
                    "from": "exercises",
                    "localField": "user_id",
                    "foreignField": "user_id",
                    "as": "exercises"
                }
            },
            {
                "$unwind": {
                    "path": "$exercises",
                    "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
                }
            },
            {
                "$redact": {
                    "$cond": [{
                            "$and": [{
                                    "$gte": ["$exercises.exercise_date", "$exercises.start_date"]
                                },
                                {
                                    "$lte": ["$exercises.exercise_date", "$exercises.end_date"]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "$$KEEP",
                        "$$PRUNE"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "$group": {
                    "_id": "$_id",
                    "goal_id": {
                        "$first": "$goal_id"
                    },
                    "exercises": {
                        "$push": "$exercises"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        function(err, goalOut) {
            console.log(goalOut)
            if (err) {
                //Error: send error to user
                throw err
            } else {
                if (goalOut.length == 0) { //No goals, do nothing
                    return response.json({
                        success: true,
                        msg: "No Goal",
                        statusCode: 0,
                        payload: 'na'
                    });
                } else { //User as goals + matching exercise
                    //console.log(goals);

                    return response.json({
                        success: true,
                        msg: "Goals",
                        payload: goalOut
                    });
                }
            }
        });
};
```

Which outputs the following:

```
[ { _id: 58c3e0b1c8a467055d900595, goal_id: 1, exercises: [] },
  { _id: 58c3e0adc8a467055d900594, goal_id: 2, exercises: [] } ]
```

As you can see the exercises data is actually an empty array although in in the original post below data was present.

SOLVED

I forgot to take note of the pulsation of collection names

Comment: You need result of queryExercise result in main function?? Now whats the error in executing the above code??

Comment: I believe the issue may be here `"$exercises.drink_date"`; you don't have `drink_date` in your `Exercises` schema.

Comment: Awkwardly as I was typing that out I, for some reason, was thinking about having a drink. Having just checked my source code it should be goal_date.  I have amended the post.

Comment: I found the solution. MongoDB was using the plural version of the collection. Correcting and it works like a charm. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to execute a single query using the aggregation framework pipeline i.e. use the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)**, **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** and **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** pipeline stages to return the documents you want via an **[`aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate)** pipeline execution.

In the following example, the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** pipeline allows you to perform a "left join" to the other collection on the `user_id` field, flatten the array of documents produced as a result of the join with **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** and then filter the documents in the pipeline with **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** which returns all documents that match the date condition using **[`$$KEEP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#keep)** and discards otherwise using the **[`$$PRUNE`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#prune)** system variables:

```
module.exports.generateGoal = function(request, response) {

    //User ID 
    var user_id = new ObjectId(request.params.id);

    //Goal query
    Goals.aggregate([
        { "$match": { "user_id": user_id, "active_goal": true } },
        {
            "$lookup": {
                "from": "exercises",
                "localField": "user_id",
                "foreignField": "user_id",
                "as": "exercises"
            }
        },
        { "$unwind": "$exercises" },
        {
            "$redact": {
                "$cond": [
                    {
                        "$and": [
                            { "$gte": ["$exercises.exercise_date", "$start_date"] },
                            { "$lt": ["$exercises.exercise_date", "$end_date"] }
                        ]
                    },
                    "$$KEEP",
                    "$$PRUNE"
                ]
            }
        }
    ], function(err, goals) {
        if (err) {
            //Error: send error to user
            throw err
        } else {
            if (goals.length == 0) { //No goals, do nothing
                return response.json({
                    success: true,
                    msg: "No Goal"
                });
            } else { //User as goals + matching exercise
                console.log(goals);
                return goals
            }
        }
    });
};
```

---

Keep in mind that for each input document, **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** outputs `n` documents where `n` is the number of array elements and can be zero for an empty array, hence there may be a need to group the documents
again after the **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** pipeline as there will be potentially `(n-x)` documents per goal where `n` is the length of the `exercises` array produced after **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** and `x` is the number of filtered out elements after **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)**.

---

### UPDATE

As follow-up to the above, to group the documents and get the expected output you need a final **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline that groups the documents by the `_id` key, use the **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** accumulator operator to return the `goal_id` field and create the `exercises` array using the **[`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push)** accumulator. The following pipeline demonstrates this:

```
module.exports.generateGoal = function(request, response) {

    //User ID 
    var user_id = new ObjectId(request.params.id);

    //Goal query
    Goals.aggregate([
        { "$match": { "user_id": user_id, "active_goal": true } },
        {
            "$lookup": {
                "from": "exercises",
                "localField": "user_id",
                "foreignField": "user_id",
                "as": "exercises"
            }
        },
        { "$unwind": "$exercises" },
        {
            "$redact": {
                "$cond": [
                    {
                        "$and": [
                            { "$gte": ["$exercises.exercise_date", "$start_date"] },
                            { "$lt": ["$exercises.exercise_date", "$end_date"] }
                        ]
                    },
                    "$$KEEP",
                    "$$PRUNE"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$_id",
                "goal_id": { "$first": "$goal_id" },
                "exercises": { "$push": "$exercises" }
            }
        }
    ], function(err, goals) {
        if (err) {
            //Error: send error to user
            throw err
        } else {
            if (goals.length == 0) { //No goals, do nothing
                return response.json({
                    success: true,
                    msg: "No Goal"
                });
            } else { //User as goals + matching exercise
                console.log(goals);
                return goals
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Great response which has been very helpful. For the future i am interested in returning multiple exercises per goal - is this possible easily with the current implementation?

Comment: Yes, that should be possible. What expected output do you have in mind? Would you mind updating your question with that?

Comment: I've updated my answer, hopefully that should fix. Let me know how that fares.

Comment: chridam, again your generosity in helping here is greatly appreciated. I have played around with the syntax you provided and encountered an issue. I have updated the first post.